# Mongo merge results

Tags: mongodb

Hello guys I have 3 collections that have dbref, where I wanted to mount a result similar to the one shown below but I couldn't get to something satifatorio using any aggregate can you indicate a better way?

**Coolections:**

- data1 - Main data_reference1
- referenced in data1 data_reference2
- referenced in data_reference2

```
/* EXAMPLE RECORD data1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604fafd443487df824aeca61"),
    "name" : "doc1",
    "reference_data1_list" : [ 
        {
            "data_reference" : ObjectId("604fb00643487df824aeca91"),
            "user_add" : "USER01"
        }, 
        {
            "data_reference" : ObjectId("604fb00d43487df824aeca9b"),
            "user_add" : "USER01"
        }, 
        {
            "data_reference" : ObjectId("604fb01743487df824aecaa7"),
            "user_add" : "USER02"
        }
    ]
}

/* EXAMPLE RECORDS data_reference1 */
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604fb00643487df824aeca91"),
    "reference_desc" : "Test Referenced Field 01",
    "reference_data2" : ObjectId("604fb24743487df824aecd14")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604fb00d43487df824aeca9b"),
    "reference_desc" : "Test Referenced Field 02",
    "reference_data2" : ObjectId("604fb24743487df824aecd14")
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604fb01743487df824aecaa7"),
    "reference_desc" : "Test Referenced Field 03",
    "reference_data2" : ObjectId("604fb25743487df824aecd27")
}

/* EXAMPLE RECORDS data_reference2 */
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604fb24743487df824aecd14"),
    "name" : "Student"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604fb25743487df824aecd27"),
    "name" : "Theacher"
}
```

Desired result:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("604fafd443487df824aeca61"),
  "name": "doc1",
  "reference_data1_list": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("604fb00643487df824aeca91"),
      "reference_desc": "Test Referenced Field 01",
      "reference_data2": {
        "_id": ObjectId("604fb24743487df824aecd14"),
        "name": "Student"
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("604fb00d43487df824aeca9b"),
      "reference_desc": "Test Referenced Field 02",
      "reference_data2": {
        "_id": ObjectId("604fb24743487df824aecd14"),
        "name": "Student"
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "604fb01743487df824aecaa7",
      "reference_desc": "Test Referenced Field 03",
      "reference_data2": {
        "_id": ObjectId("604fb25743487df824aecd27"),
        "name": "Theacher"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't have much skill with the mongo and I didn't find any similar example to be able to use in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```js
db.data1.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$reference_data1_list" },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "data_reference1",
            let: {
                data_ref: "$reference_data1_list.data_reference",
                user_add: "$reference_data1_list.user_add"
            },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$data_ref"] }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $addFields: { user_add: "$$user_add" }
                }
            ],
            as: "reference_data1_list"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$reference_data1_list" },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "data_reference2",
            localField: "reference_data1_list.reference_data2",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "reference_data1_list.reference_data2"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$reference_data1_list.reference_data2" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            name: { $first: "$name" },
            reference_data1_list: { $push: "$reference_data1_list" }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604fafd443487df824aeca61"),
    "name" : "doc1",
    "reference_data1_list" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("604fb00643487df824aeca91"),
            "reference_desc" : "Test Referenced Field 01",
            "reference_data2" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("604fb24743487df824aecd14"),
                "name" : "Student"
            },
            "user_add" : "USER01"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("604fb00d43487df824aeca9b"),
            "reference_desc" : "Test Referenced Field 02",
            "reference_data2" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("604fb24743487df824aecd14"),
                "name" : "Student"
            },
            "user_add" : "USER01"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("604fb01743487df824aecaa7"),
            "reference_desc" : "Test Referenced Field 03",
            "reference_data2" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("604fb25743487df824aecd27"),
                "name" : "Theacher"
            },
            "user_add" : "USER02"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: any idea for preserve `"user_add" : "USER02"` in `"reference_data1_list"` ?